# What does gsutil use under the hood?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gsutil

When I am transferring a local file to a Google Cloud Storage bucket with the Google CLoud utility gsutil, what protocol does it use?  Encrypted SSH tunnel?

Answer (score 2):

Gsutil uses the [apitools](https://github.com/google/apitools) and [boto](https://github.com/boto/boto) libraries to send HTTPS requests (to GCS's JSON and XML APIs, respectively).  You can see details about each request gsutil is making on your behalf if you run gsutil with the `-D` option, e.g.:

```
gsutil -D cp /some/file.txt gs://my-bucket/
```

Answer (score 1):

It should be using HTTPS to upload to the Google Cloud Storage API. This [Python client library](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-python/latest/_modules/google/cloud/storage/blob.html#Blob) shows some details of that connection.